# How to loop through a file and use the values in a bash or python script?

Tags: python, bash

I have a numbers.txt file which contains thousands of numbers in the following format

```
00001
00002
```

I need to create a Python or Bash script which will take each number and replace xyz as seen below with each of the values in a new file. Below is the format:

```
echo '{"id":1,"jsonrpc":"2.0", "method":"dummy.endpoint","params":[123, [xyz]]}' | nc -N localhost 30000 | json_pp
```

So the final output would like:

```
echo '{"id":1,"jsonrpc":"2.0", "method":"dummy.endpoint","params":[123, [00001]]}' | nc -N localhost 30000 | json_pp
echo '{"id":1,"jsonrpc":"2.0", "method":"dummy.endpoint","params":[123, [00002]]}' | nc -N localhost 30000 | json_pp
```

How can this be done in either a Python or Bash script?

Comment: please update the question with the code you've tried and the (wrong) output generated by your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done in Python.

```py
with open("numbers.txt", "rt") as numbers:
     with open("output.txt", "wt") as output:
         num = numbers.readline()
         while num:
             output.write('echo \'{"id":1,"jsonrpc":"2.0", "method":"dummy.endpoint","params":[123, [%s]]}\' | nc -N localhost 30000 | json_pp\n' % num)
             num = numbers.readline()
```

Explanation.

Your target line needs to be modified slightly to work with python.

I replaced the single quote characters (') with escaped single quotes (\') so that way they don't get confused with the single quotes used to separate the string from the Python program.

I also replaced xyz with %s which is a placeholder for a value that comes from somewhere else.

I used the % operator to perform a substitution of the placeholder with a number from the file.

Finally I included a newline (\n) at the end of the line because you need to specify the ends of lines when writing files in Python.

The rest of the program takes the values line-by-line from the file numbers.txt and keeps them in the variable `num`. When the program reaches the end of the file `num` will have a value of "" and the while loop will terminate.

Notice that this program will create or overwrite a file called "output.txt" which contains the output. You also could have printed the output to the terminal using the `print` function.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working demo in python

```
query = ("echo \'{\"id\":1,\"jsonrpc\":\"2.0\", \"method\":\"dummy.endpoint\",\"params\":[123, [xyz]]}\' "
     "| nc -N localhost 30000 | json_pp")

with open("numbers.txt", 'r') as f:
f1 = open("output.txt", "a")
for line in f:
    val = line.strip("\n")
    f1.write(query.replace("xyz", f"{val}") + "\n")
f1.close()
```

Comment: @Semie Bencherif 
following line is necessary to get the proper output in the file
line.strip("\n"), Unless you strip the end line character while reading the input you will not get the required result.

Answer (score 0):

If the input is never going to be more than thousands of numbers, a pure Bash solution may be practical.  Try this [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/)-clean code:

```
while read -r num || [[ -n $num ]]; do
    printf 'echo '\''{"id":1,"jsonrpc":"2.0", "method":"dummy.endpoint","params":[123, [%s]]}'\'' | nc -N localhost 30000 | json_pp\n' "$num"
done <numbers.txt >output.txt
```

- `|| [[ -n $num ]]` is to support input files where the final line is not terminated.  See [BashFAQ/001 (How can I read a file (data stream, variable) line-by-line (and/or field-by-field)?)](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001).
- The code runs in around 0.5s with a 10 thousand line input file on my (very basic) test system.  You would need to use Python to get acceptable speed with significantly larger input files.